# Получить число с плавающей точкой (float) из short int

Tags: c, math

Есть число `short int x = 29798_10 = 7466_16 = 0111 0100 0110 0110_2` из этого нужно сделать `float y = 011.1 0100 0110 0110_2 = 3.637451171875` как получить это [число](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=011.1010001100110_2) при помощи бинарных операторов?

Comment: Приведение указателей?

Comment: Можно подробнее, как это?

Comment: Я думал, вам нужно преобразовать  int в эквивалентное по бинарному представлению float. Если с фиксированной точкой, то это не подходит.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чистый и переносимый вариант на всякие странные архитектуры:

```
float y = (float)x / (1U << (sizeof(short)*CHAR_BIT - 3));
```

Или по-простому:

```
float y = (float)x / 0x2000;
```

Answer (score 2):

Это: `011.1 0100 0110 0110_2` вовсе не float формат, а число с фиксированной точкой. И никаких операций делать не нужно, достаточно знать положение точки.

Для перевода же во float нужно разделить на 2^(16-k), где k - количество разрядов до точки.